# Characterize those power series that converge uniformly on ($-\infty$, $\infty$).

Tags: power-series

My question:

Characterize those power series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_{k}(x-c)^{k}$ that converge uniformly on ($-\infty, \,\infty$).
What does it mean to characterize a power series?

Let {$a_{k}$} be a sequence of coefficients for a power series. By definition, the radius of convergence $R = \infty$ if $\limsup\sqrt[k]{|a_{k}|} = 0$.

Comment: It means giving a non-trivial if-and-only-if condition.

Comment: Give a set of necessary and sufficient condition, such that a given property will hold.

Answer (score 8):

These power series are precisely the polynomials.

The partial sums of a uniformly convergent power series must be a Cauchy sequence in the sup-norm. Let $S_n(x)$ be the $n$-th partial sum. Uniform convergence implies
$$
\forall \epsilon > 0 \, \exists N > 0 \, \ni \, \forall n > N \, \forall x \in \mathbb{R} \, 
|S_{n+1}(x) - S_n(x)| = |a_{n+1}(x-c)^{n+1}| < \epsilon
$$
Now this is only possible if $a_{n+1} = 0$. Therefore the condition becomes
$$
\exists N > 0 \, \ni \, \forall n > N \, a_{n+1} = 0
$$
i.e. this is a polynomial.

Comment: What is the sup-norm?

Comment: @Garrett Supremum norm or uniform norm, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_norm

Comment: This is so helpful!

Answer (score 2):

A *characterization* in this case is a condition on the series (that is, on its coefficients) that is equivalent to uniform convergence in the whole real line.