# understanding someone proof :Characterize those power series that converge uniformly on (−∞, ∞).

Tags: calculus, power-series

[Characterize those power series that converge uniformly on ($-\infty$, $\infty$).](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2377139/characterize-those-power-series-that-converge-uniformly-on-infty-infty)

I can't understand why he wrote, "Now this is only possible if an+1=0."
for any epsilon, there is another N and another an+1 it seems he only proves that an+1 converges to 0 but not equal to 0.
could someone assist?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the function
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
f:\Bbb R &\longrightarrow& \Bbb R\\
x & \mapsto & \vert a(x-c)^n\vert
\end{array}$$
for some constants $a,c\in \Bbb R$ and some $n\in \Bbb N_0$.

If $a,n \neq 0$ we find that $f(x_n)\rightarrow \infty$ for $x_n \rightarrow \pm \infty$. So if $f$ is bounded ie. satisfies $\forall x: f(x) < C$ for some $C\in \Bbb R$, then either $a$ or $n$ has to be 0. If we know that $n\geq 1$, $a$ has to be 0.

Comment: sorry still have trouble to understand do you mean that is a is now constant, and as x goes to infinity |a|< ε/| (x−c)^n|  so, therefore, a is zero?
am I correct?

Comment: @mathmaster sorry for the late edit, I hope this clears things up. Merry Christmas!

Comment: @mathmaster your comment is indeed the way to formally prove that $a=0$ if we know $n\geq 1$.